# rails 6.6.1.1 serializer attributes with regex fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

In my model I have two attributes which store regular expressions
label_regex, and text_regex

```
class RegularExpression < ApplicationRecord
    serialize label_regex
    serialize text_regex
end
```

But When i try to access them i get an error

```
regex = RegularExpression.find(16)
regex[:label_regex]
Psych::DisallowedClass Exception: Tried to load unspecified class: Regexp
```

grateful for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Even though most of the answers posted relate to yaml, its also true for activerecord
so adding

```
config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Regexp]
in config/application.rb
```

fixed the issue